# OS X: mounting my camera as R/W

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, read-only, automount

When I jack my camera into my Mac mini it gets auto-mounted as read only:

```
/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/NO NAME (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)
```

I would like to mount it as "write" to be able to copy some pictures onto the SD-card inside, but simply

sudo mount -rw -t msdos /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/Whatever

doesn't work ("permission denied"), only `mount -r` works. Anybody know why and how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: You can't do what the camera doesn't let you.

Comment: Are you sure that's the reason; the camera? How do you know it's not OS X?

Comment: Seemed like the camera's fault. Sent a support question to Panasonic about it.